# External keyboard, typing blind

Tags: external-keyboard, notes

Here's the same question, but I don't think it's well answered because the phone will keep registering touches when in-pocket:
[Method of typing input while the screen is off](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195612/method-of-typing-input-while-the-screen-is-off)

I'd like to be able to take out a small Bluetooth keyboard and immediately start typing some notes into it like an Alphasmart but without seeing what I'm typing. How can I do that?

The first issue, as far as I can tell, is the screenlock.
The second issue might be delay as the keyboard wakes the phone and switching to a text editor of some kind.

Comment: If your phone has a hardware button for the camera you may be able reconfigure the button to start your text app even over the lock screen. Not sure if there is an app that already can do this.